# Laravel 4: Redirecting when invalid route

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to treat the invalid requests on my Laravel app, something like redirecting to the root will work just fine, but I can't manage to do it.

In the documentation and around stackoverflow I saw this is always the solution:

```
App::missing(function() {
    # handle the error
});
```

I thought that would just go to the routes file but no. Then I saw in some post it should be in the `app/start/global.php` file but it still didn't work.

In the docs it says I can "register an error handle". Is that what I should do? What does this mean? What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately this can be put anywhere, but `app/start/global.php` is probably the best place for it.

```
App::missing(function($exception)
{
    return Response::view('errors.missing', array(), 404);
});
```

Try putting this in there. In fact, if you've just setup a fresh installation, you should already have one there.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can register an error handler, like so;

```
App::error(function(Exception $exception, $code)
{ 
    //Now you can check for different exceptions and handle each on their own way.
}
```

This will be for PHP general `Exception` class which will make all exceptions go here, but you can change `Exception` to the specific `Exception` class of you own and handle it accordingly.

`App::missing` will generally be called when a page within your site has not been found, allowing you to show a default page for when users have found a non existing page. So if you are wanting to handle missing pages, use `App::missing` else use `App::error`.